# Sort by key then value which will then be grouped up...pyspark

Tags: sorting, pyspark

So I'm trying to sort data in this format...

```
[((0, 4), 3), ((4, 0), 3), ((1, 6), 1), ((3, 2), 3), ((0, 5), 1)...
```

Ascending by key and then descending by value.  I'm able to achieve this via...

```
test = test.sortBy(lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
```

which would give me based on shortened version above...

```
[((0, 4), 3), ((0, 5), 1), ((1, 6), 1), ((3, 2), 3), ((4, 0), 3)...
```

The problem I'm having is that after the sorting I no longer want the value but do need to retain the sort after grouping the data. So...

```
test = test.map(lambda x: (x[0][0],x[0][1]))
```

Gives me...

```
[(0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 6), (3, 2), (4, 0)...
```

Which is still in the order I need it but I need the elements to be grouped up by key.  I then use this command...

```
test = test.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1])))
```

But in the process I lose the sorting.  Is there any way retain?

Comment: You can use `sort` i.e `test = test.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1].sort()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to retain the order by changing the format of the tuple...

```
test = test.map(lambda x: (x[0][0],(x[0][1],x[1]))
test = test.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], sorted(list(x[1]), key=lambda x: (x[0],-x[1]))))

[(0, [(4, 3), (5, 1)] ...
```

which leaves me with the value (2nd element in the tuple) that I want to get rid of but took care of that too...

```
test = test.map(lambda x: (x[0], [e[0] for e in x[1]]))
```

Feels a bit hacky but not sure how else it could be done.